# How to dynamically add ng-readonly attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

In my JS code, I want to create an `input` element with `ng-readonly` attribute. My code is as follows:

```
    var newClientNameInputBox = document.createElement("input");
    newClientNameInputBox.name = "clientNames";
    newClientNameInputBox.type = "text";
    newClientNameInputBox.className = "form-control";
    newClientNameInputBox["ng-readonly"] = "setReadonly";
```

However, `newClientNameInputBox` turns out to have only the attributes `name`, `type`, and `class`. The `ng-readonly` attribute is missing. How should I go about adding an `ng-readonly` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of: Compiler (aka $complie) is an AngularJS service which traverses the DOM looking for attributes. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

Something like this should work:

```
var template = '<input name="clientNames" type="text" class="form-control" ng-readonly="setReadonly" />';
var newClientNameInputBox = angular.element(template);
var $compile = ...; // injected into your code
var scope = ...; // { setReadonly : true }
var parent = ...; // DOM Parent where you want to drop your input    

var compiledElement = $compile(newClientNameInputBox)(scope);
parent.appendChild(compiledElement);
```